# How to let unregistered user click 'submit article' and then redirect to Login form, but not 403 error?

Tags: joomla, authentication, http-status-code-403

My website uses joomla 2.5, I add a link on my main menu to submit new article, but when unregistered user click this link, it will show an 403 error,"You don't have permission to access this URL on this server." But i don't want this page show up, i want website redirect to Login form.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

http://saraakash.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/joomla403-page-to-login-redirect/

> Modify the /templates/system/error.php.
>
> defined( ‘_JEXEC’ ) or die( ‘Restricted access’ );
>
> and the place the following code after the code above:
>
> $ReferTo = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; $ReferTo =
>   base64_encode($ReferTo);
>
> if ($this->error->code = ’403′) {
>   header(‘Location:index.php?option=com_user&view=login&ReferTo=’.$ReferTo);
>   die(); }

Just had to search for **joomla 403 redirect to login** and the above was the first result

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to hack core files (which is a bad idea as it could get wiped out with the next security update), there are simpler, built-in, ways to do this.

1. Change your "Submit new Article" link to "Registered" (or whatever group you've setup) that way users of the website won't see the menu until they log in.
   **OR** if you don't want the menu hidden from users that aren't logged in...
2. A bit more complicated way, but definitely worthwhile, is to create a "[Guest User Group](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_hide_something_from_logged_in_users?)"

   1. Once you've created your **Guest** group, as in the first option, change your existing menu item to "Registered" (or whatever group you've setup) access.
   2. Then create an identically named "Submit new Article" menu item but link it to the "User Login" menu type and set it's access to the "Guest" group you just created.
   3. Set the "Login Redirect" option to the URL of your real "Submit new Article" menu